# Python unittesting based on stdout from program -- not all tests running, strange (and changin) result. Flushing problem?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm having trouble creating tests that review the stout output of a program. The issue is that not all tests run - but this also seems to vary somewhat. Strange error; I've been playing around with flushing, thinking that that's the issue, but the problem persists.

The test code is here...

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
import contextlib
import unittest
import tested


class ExampleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        f = StringIO();
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
            tested.main()
        f.flush()
        self.output = f.getvalue()

    def test_n_value(self):
        print("testing n...", end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        self.assertTrue('44.27715216205352' in self.output, "n value should be 44.27715216205352")
        print("OK")

    def test_FV_value(self):
        print("testing FV...", end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        self.assertTrue('25937.424601000024' in self.output, "FV value should be 25937.424601000024")
        print("OK")

    def test_r_value(self):
        print("testing r...", end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        self.assertTrue('0.117461894308801895' in self.output, "r value should be 0.17461894308801895")
        print("OK")

    def test_PV_value(self):
        print("testing PV...", end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        self.assertTrue('3855.432894295314' in self.output, "PV value should be 3855.432894295314")
        print("OK")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The code that is being tested is here...

```
import math

def main():
    # Calculate FV given r=0.10, n=10, PV=10000
    r = 0.10
    n = 10
    PV = 10000
    FV = PV * (1 + r) ** n
    print(FV)
    # Calculate PV given r=0.10, n=10, FV=10000
    r = 0.10
    n = 10
    FV = 10000
    PV = FV / (1 + r) ** n
    print(PV)
    # Calculate n given r=0.07, PV=10000, FV=200000
    r = 0.07
    FV = 200000
    PV = 10000
    n = math.log(FV / PV) / math.log(1 + r)
    print(n)
    # Calculate r given n=10, FV=100000, PV=20000
    # print(math.log())
    FV = 100000
    PV = 20000
    n = 10
    r = (FV / PV) ** (1 / n) - 1
    print(r)

main()
```

Comment: Why not write a function that _returns_ the value, and test that? Then main just calls it and prints the result.

Comment: Because this is the format/requirement for the main program. The question (and problem) is associated with unittesting stdout -- and the approach in the unittest above is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.... (the flushes were not necessary, and the 'getvalue()' call needed to be within the with statement....

```
import io
import sys
import contextlib
import unittest
import tested

class ExampleTestcaset(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        f = io.StringIO()
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
            tested.main()
            self.output = f.getvalue()

    def test_n_value(self):
        print("Testing n: ", end="")
        self.assertTrue('44.27715216205352' in self.output, self.output + "n value should be 44.27715216205352")
        print("OK")

    def test_FV_value(self):
        print("Testing FV: ", end="")
        self.assertTrue('25937.424601000024' in self.output, "FV value should be 25937.424601000024")
        print("OK")

    def test_r_value(self):
        print("Testing r: ", end="")
        self.assertTrue('0.17461894308801895' in self.output, "r value should be 0.17461894308801895")
        print("OK")

    def test_PV_value(self):
        print("Testing PV: ", end="")
        self.assertTrue('3855.432894295314' in self.output, "PV value should be 3855.432894295314")
        print("OK")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```